# Does/Can Asynchronous Session method live longer than the servlet Call

Tags: java, asynchronous, ejb-3.1

I don't know if its a good question. 
EJB 3.1 brings the possibility to tag the methods with asychronous. 
I wonder if the aschronous call lives longer than the servlet thread or if the servlet thread waits in background until the process is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, thread does not wait in background. You can test this easily by calling long lasting task and monitor it being still alive after session had timed out (just adjust very short timeout).

Connected problem is needlessly reserved resources in the cases when client never calls Future.get(). For avoiding them to be reserved whole application runtime, specification allows timeouts:

> An EJB Container Provider is permitted to define a timeout value that
>   governs the maximum amount of time the container maintains result
>   values for completed asynchronous invocations. The configuration of
>   such a timeout is beyond the scope of this specification.